# Drawing line doesn't follow finger after first stroke

Tags: android, paint

I am making an activity that allows someone to sign their signature on a blank screen.  Currently when they are drawing, a line will follow their finger as they write it.  For some reason, after I lift up my finger and try to draw a second line, there is no longer a line following my finger; however the line still appears after I lift my finger.  This is important as many people lift up their finger to write their last name, and it would be better for them to be able to see what they are drawing as they do so.  Here is relevant code below:

In my View:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
    }
```

I have a "clear" menu option that resets the entire screen to a blank background.  If I use this after making one stroke, the line will start to follow me again.

```
public void clearView() {
    mv = new MyView(this);
    mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mv.setBackgroundResource(0);
    setContentView(mv);
}
```

Any help or even resourceful links is appreciated.  I spent quite a while searching for a solution to this but found no occurrences of this specific issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone some day, my solution was found by removing this line 
`mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));`

from the bottom of my method `private void touch_up()`

Cheers.